# Adds the effect of the hover on the chilled element using the styled component

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, styled-components

Good evening everyone.
I'm trying to build a component using React and use the Style Component to add the CSS.
But when adding the Hover effect to the element (a), the effect is also reflected on all the elements inside the (a). As in the picture
[image]

```
<Section>
<PortLogin>
<h1>Welcome to Your Profettional Community</h1>

 <ul>
   <a href="##" ><li href="##">Search For a job</li><i className="fas fa-chevron-right"></i> 
 </a>
   <a  href="##"><li href="##">Find a Person You Know</li><i className="fas fa-chevron-right"> 
 </i></a>
   <a  href="##"><li href="##">Learn a new skill</li><i className="fas fa-chevron-right"></i> 
 </a>
   
 </ul>
 </PortLogin>
 <img src="Img/SectionImg.svg" alt="Img Section "></img>

  </Section>
```

my styled-components

```
const Section=styled.div`

display: flex;
justify-content: start;
 flex-wrap:wrap;
 margin-top: 40px;

 & img{
   width: 500px;
   position: absolute;
   right: 0;
     }
 `;

 const PortLogin=styled.div`
 margin-top: 25px;
 display:flex;
 flex-direction:column;
 justify-content:space-around;

 & ul{
  margin-top:50px;
 
     & :hover {
     box-shadow: 3px 3px 8px 2px #00000040;
      }
      }

    & ul>a{
       text-decoration:none;
       padding: 25px 20px;
       margin-bottom: 20px;
       width:70%;
       list-style: none;  
       display: flex;
       justify-content:space-between;
       border: 1px solid #d3cccc;
       border-radius: 13px;
       font-size: larger
     }

      ul li a{
      text-decoration: none;
      color:Black;
     }
      `
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem. The solution is very simple. I have to use Direct Child

```
const PortLogin = styled.div`
   margin-top: 25px;
   display: flex;
   flex-direction: column;
   justify-content: space-around;

    & > ul {
    margin-top: 50px;
     }

     & ul > a {
     text-decoration: none;
     padding: 25px 20px;
     margin-bottom: 20px;
     width: 70%;
     list-style: none;
     display: flex;
     justify-content: space-between;
     border: 1px solid #d3cccc;
     border-radius: 13px;
     font-size: larger;
      }

       ul > li > a {
       text-decoration: none;
       color: Black;
        }
       ul > li > a:hover {
       text-decoration: underline;
        }
         `;
          `
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to move your `hover` class out of your `ul` tag (which is wrapping all of the elements within, so all lists and links within it.

I assume you want the links to be hoverable only, so something like this should be more appropriate:

```
const PortLogin = styled.div`
  margin-top: 25px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-around;

  & ul {
    margin-top: 50px;
  }

  & ul > a {
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 25px 20px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    width: 70%;
    list-style: none;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    border: 1px solid #d3cccc;
    border-radius: 13px;
    font-size: larger;
  }

  ul li a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: Black;
  }
  ul li a:hover {
    text-decoration: underline;
  }
`;
`
```